# Micronaut http client doesn't recognise fields

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I receive the following json from a rest service.

```
{
  "AccessControlRecords": {
    "OccasionRecords": [
      {
        "Type": "",
        "BookingNr": "91376",
        "BookingRow": "1",
        "FacilityID": "OIHAL",
        "ObjectID": "STYRK",
        "PartOfObjectId": "",
        "PartOfObjectName": "",
        "FacilityName": "Odense Idrætshal",
        "ObjectName": "Styrketræningslokale",
        "BookFromDate": "17.08.2019",
        "BookToDate": "23.05.2020",
        "OccasionDate": "2020-01-04 09:00",
        "OccasionToDate": "2020-01-04 10:00",
        "FomKlo": "09:00",
        "TomKlo": "10:00",
        "TimeBefore": "0",
        "TimeAfter": "0",
        "Weekday": 0,
        "BookStatus": "",
        "KortReg": "",
        "CustomerID": "",
        "CustomerName": "Svømmeklubben Frem",
        "TypeOfBooking": "E",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "Cards": null,
        "FunctionCode1": 0,
        "FunctionCode2": 0,
        "FunctionCode3": 0,
        "FunctionCode4": "",
        "Text1": "",
        "Text2": "",
        "Text3": "",
        "Text4": "",
        "EndUser": "",
        "Activity": "Styrketræning"
      },
      {
        "Type": "",
        "BookingNr": "90443",
        "BookingRow": "1",
        "FacilityID": "OIHAL",
        "ObjectID": "STYRK",
        "PartOfObjectId": "",
        "PartOfObjectName": "",
        "FacilityName": "Odense Idrætshal",
        "ObjectName": "Styrketræningslokale",
        "BookFromDate": "02.11.2019",
        "BookToDate": "28.03.2020",
        "OccasionDate": "2020-01-04 14:00",
        "OccasionToDate": "2020-01-04 16:30",
        "FomKlo": "14:00",
        "TomKlo": "16:30",
        "TimeBefore": "0",
        "TimeAfter": "0",
        "Weekday": 1,
        "BookStatus": "",
        "KortReg": "",
        "CustomerID": "",
        "CustomerName": "Odense Roklub",
        "TypeOfBooking": "E",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "Cards": null,
        "FunctionCode1": 0,
        "FunctionCode2": 0,
        "FunctionCode3": 0,
        "FunctionCode4": "",
        "Text1": "",
        "Text2": "",
        "Text3": "",
        "Text4": "",
        "EndUser": "",
        "Activity": "Styrketræning"
      },
      {
        "Type": "",
        "BookingNr": "91916",
        "BookingRow": "1",
        "FacilityID": "OIHAL",
        "ObjectID": "STYRK",
        "PartOfObjectId": "DELA",
        "PartOfObjectName": "Delt styrketræning (A)",
        "FacilityName": "Odense Idrætshal",
        "ObjectName": "Styrketræningslokale",
        "BookFromDate": "24.08.2019",
        "BookToDate": "20.06.2020",
        "OccasionDate": "2020-01-04 10:00",
        "OccasionToDate": "2020-01-04 14:00",
        "FomKlo": "10:00",
        "TomKlo": "14:00",
        "TimeBefore": "0",
        "TimeAfter": "0",
        "Weekday": 0,
        "BookStatus": "",
        "KortReg": "",
        "CustomerID": "",
        "CustomerName": "* Odense Håndbold talentcenter",
        "TypeOfBooking": "E",
        "CreatedBy": "",
        "Cards": null,
        "FunctionCode1": 0,
        "FunctionCode2": 0,
        "FunctionCode3": 0,
        "FunctionCode4": "",
        "Text1": "",
        "Text2": "",
        "Text3": "",
        "Text4": "",
        "EndUser": "",
        "Activity": "Styrketræning"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ResultCode": 0,
  "ResultText": null
}
```

My data classes are defined as the following

```
data class Bookings(val AccessControlRecords: AccessControlRecords, val resultCode: Int, val resultText: String?)

data class AccessControlRecords(val OccasionRecords: List<OccasionRecords>)

data class OccasionRecords(val type: String?,
                           val BookingNr: String,
                           val bookingRow: String,
                           val FacilityID: String,
                           val ObjectID: String,
                           val PartOfObjectId: String,
                           val PartOfObjectName: String,
                           val FacilityName: String,
                           val ObjectName: String,
                           val BookFromDate: String,
                           val BookToDate: String,
                           val OccasionDate: String,
                           val OccasionToDate: String,
                           val FomKlo: String,
                           val TomKlo: String,
                           val TimeBefore: String,
                           val TimeAfter: String,
                           val Weekday: Int,
                           val BookStatus: String,
                           val KortReg: String,
                           val CustomerID: String,
                           val CustomerName: String,
                           val TypeOfBooking: String,
                           val CreatedBy: String,
                           val Cards: String,
                           val FunctionCode1: Int,
                           val FunctionCode2: Int,
                           val FunctionCode3: Int,
                           val FunctionCode4: String,
                           val Text1: String,
                           val Text2: String,
                           val Text3: String,
                           val Text4: String,
                           val EndUser: String,
                           val Activity: String)
```

My configuration class is defined as the following

```
class BookingConfiguration {
    companion object {
        const val URL = "https://something.dk"
        const val PATH = "/kmd_webapi/api/Monitor/GetFilteredAccessControlRecords?dateTimeFrom=2020-01-04&dateTimeTo=2020-01-04&facility=OIHAL&facilityObject=STYRK&partObject=&authenticationCode=xxx&type=json"
    }
}
```

The actual client is defined as the following

```
@Client(BookingConfiguration.URL)
interface BookingsClient {
    @Get(BookingConfiguration.PATH)
    fun fetchBookings(dateTimeFrom: String, dateTimeTo: String, authenticationCode: String): Flowable<Bookings>
}
```

The exception I'm getting is the following

```
01:31:59.199 [pool-1-thread-3] ERROR i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Unexpected error occurred: Error decoding JSON stream for type [T]: Instantiation of [simple type, class dk.fitfit.OccasionRecords] value failed for JSON property BookingNr due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter BookingNr which is a non-nullable type
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: dk.fitfit.Bookings["AccessControlRecords"]->java.lang.Object[0]->dk.fitfit.OccasionRecords["BookingNr"])
io.micronaut.http.codec.CodecException: Error decoding JSON stream for type [T]: Instantiation of [simple type, class dk.fitfit.OccasionRecords] value failed for JSON property BookingNr due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter BookingNr which is a non-nullable type
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: dk.fitfit.Bookings["AccessControlRecords"]->java.lang.Object[0]->dk.fitfit.OccasionRecords["BookingNr"])
    at io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec.decode(JsonMediaTypeCodec.java:123)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient.lambda$null$17(DefaultHttpClient.java:905)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:63)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.rxjava2.InstrumentedSubscriber.lambda$onNext$0(InstrumentedSubscriber.java:80)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:52)
...
```

I noticed that the property Bookings.AccessControlRecords has to be uppercase. But Bookings.resultCode and Bookings.resultText does not which I found odd. Same with AccessControlRecords.OccasionRecords. Of course I have been experimenting with different cases for the BookingNr property but to no avail.

Anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or perhaps someone has a clue about how to debug this further?

Comment: Seems quite straight forward: The json data you received does not have a required field called `BookingNr`. The call chain is `dk.fitfit.Bookings["AccessControlRecords"]->java.lang.Object[0]->dk.fitfit.OccasionRecords["BookingNr"])`, and it fails when decoding the first element of the list in `AccessControlRecords`. So you need to figure out why by checking the recieved data, or post it here to have someone else look at it

Comment: If I change the type of BookingNr and BookingRow to Int it goes on the complain about facilityID. It seems to be an issue with my strings. Any idea about how to have the http response printed? The json is the same for both chrome and curl so I would be surprised if it was different when requested by the micronaut client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @JsonProperty as shown below solved the problem.

```
data class Bookings(@JsonProperty("AccessControlRecords") val accessControlRecords: AccessControlRecords, val resultCode: Int, val resultText: String?)
```